# Error "Non-repeated field already set." when loading from Datastore into BigQuery

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore

[EDIT 20160426: This bug appears to have been solved now!]

[EDIT 20160219: Updated this question again, to reflect different error messages. See also the [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=396) I filed.]

We have a datastore table that contains a field `category`, of type `Category`, which is a custom class. The problem arises when we try to load this table into BigQuery (from a datastore backup). The resulting table should contain (simplified):

```
category.subfield1
,category.subfield2
,category.subfield3.subsubfield1
,category.subfield4
,category.subfield5
```

Instead, BigQuery wreaks havoc on the category field:

```
category_1.record.subfield1
,category_1.record.subfield2
,category_1.record.subfield3.subsubfield1
,category_1.entity.subfield1
,category_1.entity.subfield1
,category_1.entity.subfield3.subsubfield1
,category_1.entity.subfield4
,category_1.entity.subfield5
,category_1.provided
```

(Omitting a dozen of `__key__`-subfields for reasons of exposition.)

Before 20160219, the garbled output of the `category`-field was even worse, but there was a workaround: explicitly listing all the fields, including `category`, through the option `projection_fields`. Now that is no longer possible, since it results in a different error message: `Field:category [...] Entity was of unexpected kind "__record__"`

Original job-ids:

project id: 711939958575
without projection_fields: job_Qw6-ygtZNFJ-Y7W0uLEqdvOrO_8
with projection_fields: job_lzzXo92lud9r5kvW7Z1kuzFLxS4

Comment: It would be helpful if people who downvote this question add a comment here.

Comment: Please provide the project id and job id of a failing job. BigQuery engineers can use this to find more details about the failure. Cheers!

Comment: @michael-sheldon Thanks for pointing that out! I've added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We came accross the same problem when loading backups from datastore into BigQuery. We had an 'Order' Entity in which we had a nested entity 'Customer'. Ever since we added an index on one of the fields in the nested entity 'Customer', we would be getting the "Non-repeated field already set" error from BigQuery.

**The reason** was that setting an **index on** a field in the **nested entity** (e.g. Index on field *email* in Customer) created an index on the Order entity called **customer.email**. When loading data into BigQuery this results in *two fields* called **customer.email**, one from the nested Entity and one from the index.

**The solution for us** was to remove indices on nested Entities, in order to avoid these conflicts while loading datastore backups into BigQuery. Unfortunately we did have to remove all existing records in database, which for us wasn't a big problem, but alternatively you would have to make sure the Index is properly removed.

Comment: Thanks for sharing what you found out! Could you add that information to the bug request I filed? (See updated question.) I'll check whether we also have indices on some of these nested fields.

Comment: I think your explanation is correct. We have another entity with the same issue, and both entities have the same problematic subentity. Crucially, this other entity does not use ArrayList, so that's not the problem. (That had been my hypothesis.)