# When loading data from Datastore into BigQuery with the command line tool, what determines the inclusion of subfields?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore

While using the command line tool to load from Datastore into BigQuery I've noticed the following strange behaviour. When I specify what fields to include using the option *projection_fields*, there is one rather complex nested field whose subfields are not all included. I can determine no pattern in the selection of subfields. Strangely, if I don't specify *projection_fields* (i.e. include all fields), all subfields are included. (At least I have to assume so, because one of these subfields is actually causing an error, see [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941178/error-non-repeated-field-already-set-when-loading-from-datastore-into-bigquer).)

I've not been able to find any explanation of *projection_fields* except that it can only be used on top-level fields. Is there some design behind this behaviour or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the subfields excluded are simply those that are `null` everywhere. The error referred to in the question has a different cause, and does not imply that these subfields would have been loaded when `projection_fields` had not been set.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs) for Jobs config (scroll down to "configuration.load.projectionFields"). It does indeed say the following (emphasis mine):

"If sourceFormat is set to "DATASTORE_BACKUP", indicates which entity properties to load into BigQuery from a Cloud Datastore backup. Property names are case sensitive and **must be top-level properties**. If no properties are specified, BigQuery loads all properties. If any named property isn't found in the Cloud Datastore backup, an invalid error is returned in the job result."

So, to answer your question, it is indeed by design.

Comment: I'm afraid you may have misunderstood my question, or else I don't properly understand what that means. I've seen that documentation. My question is what happens when you include a nested top-level field. I would expect that to also include all nested subfields, but apparently only some subfields are included and I am wondering whether that selection is by design, and if so which, or whether it is a bug.